# Mapper for conflicts with existing mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a problem regarding update analyzer for a property in an index type. I have read the problem for this kind of error [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html). But it's not exactly the case since I only have one index type ( experimenting ) and it's unique, there is no way it can be conflicted. And this is from elasticsearch 2.3.

mappings

```
(get "/public-search/_mapping/developer")

{:public-search {:mappings {:developer {:properties {:db/id {:type "long"}, :developer/description {:type "string"}, :developer/established-date {:type "date", :format "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"}, :developer/logo-url {:type "string"}, :developer/name {:type "string"}, :developer/total-project {:type "long"}}}}}}

// I do have autocomplete analyzer in settings
(put "/public-search/_mapping/developer"
       {:properties {:developer/name {:type "string"
                                      :analyzer "autocomplete"}}})

{:error {:root_cause [{:type "illegal_argument_exception", :reason "Mapper for [developer/name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [developer/name] has different [analyzer]]"}], :type "illegal_argument_exception", :reason "Mapper for [developer/name] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [developer/name] has different [analyzer]]"}, :status 400}
```

If I create mappings before putting data in it works just fine. But I still have concerns about updating mapping at run time.
What could be wrong possibly  in this case?

Answer (score 3):

*If I create mappings before putting data in it works just fine.*

This just says it all, doesn't it?

---

If you first insert data without having a mapping, ES will guess your data types and then create the mapping according to it. Have a look at what mapping ES generates for your data.

I suggest, that it's not exactly the mapping you wanted to create.

Simple example: Insert a "String" `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`. ES will create a datetime field, even if you wanted a string field. In order to get a string field, you must have created the mapping before inserting the data.

Additionally analyzers, etc. cannot be guessed by ES. And it's (if I remember correctly) not possible to override them after data has been inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So normally, in production, if we want to make this kind of change, we have to recreate index and mappings then put data in then switch to the new node ?

Comment: Yes, that's most secure: First create index **and** mapping, then insert data. `...` could you just post the mapping ES creates when you only insert your data without creating mapping first?

Comment: what surprises me at first when I list the mapping ES created, it doesn't have `:analyzer` param on the property I want to update, I guess it's `standard` anyway. Btw, thanks for collaborating.

Comment: Yes, of course it's standard. ES can't know what your data means and how you want to analyze it. Though mapping first, then data `;)`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I recreated the index with the expected mapping...

```
# Create a temp index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0  -- curl -X PUT 'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/<temp index name>/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "path_analyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "path_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
            "path_tokenizer": {
               "type": "path_hierarchy",
               "delimiter": "."
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# Create a mapping in the temp index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0  -- curl -X PUT 'http://elasticsearch-master.utility:9200/<temp index name>/_mappings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
      "properties": {
        "activity_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        }
      }
}
'

# Reindex from the origin index to the temp index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0  -- curl  -X POST  'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"source": {
"index": "<original index name>"
},
"dest": {
"index": "<temp index name>"
}
}
' 

# Delete the origin index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0 -- curl --location --request DELETE 'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/<original index name>/'

# Recreate the origin index with setting if it has
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0  -- curl --location --request PUT 'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/<original index name>/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "path_analyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "path_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
            "path_tokenizer": {
               "type": "path_hierarchy",
               "delimiter": "."
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# Create a mapping in the index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0 -n utility -- curl -X PUT 'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/<original index name>/_mappings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
      "properties": {
        "activity_time": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        }
}
'

# Reindex from the temp index to the new origin index
kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0 -- curl  -X POST  'http://elasticsearch-master:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"source": {
"index": "<temp index name>"
},
"dest": {
"index": "<original index name>"
}
}
'
```